# Javascript class for enforcing JSON structure

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to JavaScript, so wondering what is the best approach to achive the below requirement.
I wanted to create JSON object (RPC request object), and need to enforce some structure. As I learn, JS is dynamic language hence I can add any type to an object at any time. But, I like to define a class, which I can populate to construct the JSON request.

```
var RecReq = {
            ID:{},
            HeaderLevel:{},
            Content:{} //Content object goes here
        },
        HeaderLevel = {
            HeaderID:{},
            Note:{}
        },
        Content = {
            Item: [] //Array of Item goes here
        },
        Item = {
            IDs:[]
        };

    function ReceiveObj() {
        this.RecReq = RecReq,
            this.HeaderLevel = HeaderLevel,
            this.Content = Content,
            this.Item = Item
    };
    return new ReceiveObj();
```

I am sure many things wrong with the above code. I don't think the object is created with the arrays initialized.
 On the returned object, I cannot do `push()` operation to insert an iten onto Content.

How would you approach this. Do you create an object on the fly, or better to define an object which enforces some structure.

Comment: I wouldn't bother creating a JS class just for a JSON DTO. More often than not, you're sending the DTO into some web service; if the service is implemented in a statically-typed language, let it take care of the type safety. Another approach better suited to a dynamic language would be verifying the structure of the objects your code produces with unit tests.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. I will not create a class, but construct an object on the fly. My intention was just to DOCUMENT what all the object 'can' contain so it won't raise an error at the backend. To help my learning, can you please suggest how should I have constructed the DTO (in idiomatic JS way). Should it all be in one class or the way I tried to do (different variable indicating different fields/types in the class). It feels horribly wrong, so an example would help me to think the JS way. thanks again

Comment: To document things, you can either use the server-side definition – if the endpoint is implemented using, say, .NET and WCF, this would be the data contract. (This is a good option if the service isn't some sort of public API.) Otherwise, you could look at how major Javascript libraries that use the "options hash" pattern are documented; usually, this means "lots and lots of examples describing actual use cases". So I'd say you can't go wrong with just providing a complete example of the JSON your service expects, and then documenting the purpose of the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as your code suggests, you want your instances to inherit the outer object, one approach would be to assign the prototype of the 'class' (be careful of thinking in class terms in JS - it's not a class in the Java etc sense) to the object.

```
var obj = { 
    prop_1: 'foo',
    prop_1: 'bar'
}
function Something() {
    alert(this.prop_1); //alerts "foo"
}
Something.prototype = obj;
var something = new Something();
```

This is just one way. There are many patterns for controlling inheritance (and other patterns that would achieve what you want without even going near the concept of inheritance).

As for `push()` not working, in your code, `Content` is an object, whereas `push()` is a method of the `Array` prototype. In other words, you can `push()` into an array only. Perhaps you meant `Content.Item`, which IS an array.

Lastly, I would avoid capitalising names. In JavaScript, this tends to be done only with functions that are used in class simulation (like your ReceiveObj), to denote that they should be instantiated, not merely invoked.

Comment: thank you for the help. The intention is not to inherit the outer object but to specify ReceiveObj. Content is of type (hence the fields can be set) Content. I know it can't be enforced in JS as someone can change the type anytime, but still it may be a pointer to document what all fields can the ReceiveObj contain. About push, I want to call recObj.Content.push(anItem). I think in my definition, the array is not initialized. YOu are right, I am thinking through other OOP languages.

Comment: The point is your `Content` property is an object, not an array, therefore there it has no `push()` method. The array is `Content.Items`, not `Content`. In JavaScript, initialisation and declaration is one step, not two, so your array is ready to use once you declare it. Any default (i.e. 'initialised') value is whatever you populate it with at the point of creation (in your case, nothing).